# Red Hat Satellite - Can it push out config changes to the machines it manages?

Tags: centos, rhel, satellite

Can Satellite make config changes to the machines it manages en mass? Specifically looking to change the yum.conf file on 30 machines.

I need a quick answer, google search results bring up pdf guides etc.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I'm sure it could, you could put something in the Kickstart %post section. But I think this sort of thing would best be served by Ansible or the like.